# Using Grunt to run modified scripts

Tags: gruntjs

I have an EXE, let's call it MyApp.exe
I then have a folder containing a a list of unit tests. Eg.

-MyTest1.txt
-MyTest2.txt
-MyTest3.txt
-MyTest4.txt

I'd like to run:

MyApp.exe --File=MyTest1.txt (obviously if it was MyTest2.txt that was modified I'd want to have that be the input).

any time MyTest1.txt or one of the other files are modified.

What's the simplest way to do this with Grunt?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be pretty simple.

See: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch

Search page for: 
"A very common request is to only compile files as needed. Here is an example that will only lint changed files with the jshint task:"